# SQL - Determining Standard Deviation of Count of Monthly Sales

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with sales data and am trying to determine the standard deviation of the number of monthly sales. However, I keep getting an error :(

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT O.Id,
STDEV(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(O.CreateDate), MONTH(O.CreateDate)) AS StdDeviation
FROM Orders O
```

I think the second line needs the most help. When I compile the code I get the error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

Any ideas? 
I am using SQL Server Management Studio v17.2

Here is an example of what I am trying to calculate.

**Example**

```
ID #7 might have 1 sale in January, 2 sales in February, 4 sales in March, etc.
```

I want to find the standard deviation of {1,2,4} for each ID individually.

**Sample Expected Output:**

```
Part Number  , Standard Deviation

1 , .86

2,  .83
```

Etc.

Comment: please tag the dbms being used.

Comment: I am using SQL Server Management Studio v17.2. Is that what you are asking? Sorry I'm fairly new to SQL.

Comment: Please provide sample expected output as well

Comment: Just added some in! Still stuck on this one so any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First calculate count in each month and then use that count to calculate `stdev`, Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, 
       Stdev(a.cnt) AS StdDeviation 
FROM   (SELECT O.id, 
               Year(O.createdate)  AS y, 
               Month(O.createdate) AS m, 
               Count(*)            AS cnt 
        FROM   orders o 
        GROUP  BY id, 
                  Year(O.createdate), 
                  Month(O.createdate)) a 
GROUP  BY id
```

**Complete Script**

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
  orderid int IDENTITY,
  CreateDate datetime,
  partid int

)


INSERT INTO #temp (CreateDate, partid)
  VALUES ('1/1/2017', 7),
  ('2/1/2017', 7),
  ('2/15/2017', 7),
  ('3/1/2017', 7),
  ('3/7/2017', 7),
  ('3/15/2017', 7),
  ('3/30/2017', 7),
  ('1/1/2017', 8),
  ('2/1/2017', 8),
  ('3/1/2017', 8),
  ('3/7/2017', 8),
  ('3/15/2017', 8)



SELECT
  a.partid,
  STDEV(a.cnt) AS StdDeviation
FROM (SELECT
  partid,
  YEAR(O.CreateDate) AS y,
  MONTH(O.CreateDate) AS m,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM #temp o
GROUP BY partid,
         YEAR(O.CreateDate),
         MONTH(O.CreateDate)) a
GROUP BY partid

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are aiming for something like this:

```
SELECT YEAR(O.CreateDate), MONTH(O.CreateDate),
       STDEV(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS StdDeviation
FROM Orders O
GROUP BY YEAR(O.CreateDate), MONTH(O.CreateDate);
```

If you include an `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause, you will get a "cumulative" standard deviation.

Comment: This does run without error - so we're moving in the right direction!! Thank you very much for your help. But this is not exactly what I was hoping for.  What I want is two columns - the ID (given by O.ID) and the standard deviation of monthly sales. As an example, Part ID #15 might have 2 sales in January, 3 in Feb, and so on. I want to take the standard deviation of the monthly sales count.